# WPF: Grid visibility fade out not behave as fade in

Tags: wpf, animation, grid, storyboard

So i have this `Grid`:

```
<Grid x:Name="notificarionGrid" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

And i want to change its `Visibility` value with animation, so i have this 2 `Storyboard`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="fadeIn">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="fadeOut">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:5.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
        </Storyboard>
```

Code behind:

**FADE IN**

```
Storyboard storyboard = Resources["fadeIn"] as Storyboard;
            storyboard.Begin(notificarionGrid);
```

**FADE OUT**

```
Storyboard storyboard = Resources["fadeOut"] as Storyboard;
            storyboard.Begin(notificarionGrid);
```

The only problem is that in fade out the `Grid` is disappear immediately not like fade in that takes 2 seconds.

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: in your fadeout storyboard, you have visibility set to Hidden. Should this not be visible?

Comment: So what i need to change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` that sets the `Visibility` property to `Hidden` from the `Storyboard`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="fadeOut">
    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
</Storyboard>
```

If you hide the element before you animate its `Opacity` property, you won't be able to see the fade out animation.

Comment: I have change my Grid Visibility from Hidden into Collapsed and i want that after the fadeOut finish my Grid become Collapsed again (because my element ToolTip that the grid take place while Visible is disable) -- any code that i need to add ?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.